# Android facebook integration for logout issue

Tags: android

```
package com.example.personalvison.socialaccount;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.model.people.Person;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements       View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,  GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {


    //Google Plus Account INtegration
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;
    private static final int PROFILE_PIC_SIZE = 400;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private boolean mIntentInProgress;
    private boolean mSignInClicked;
    private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;
    private SignInButton btnSignIn;
    private Button btnSignOut;
    private ImageView imgProfilePic;
    private TextView txtName, txtGender, txtEmialaddress;


    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
    private View otherView;
    private LoginButton facebooklogin;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private Facebook facebook;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imgProfilePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePic);
        btnSignIn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);
        btnSignOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_out);

        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnSignOut.setOnClickListener(this);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(MainActivity.this)
                  .addOnConnectionFailedListener(MainActivity.this).addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();

        txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        txtGender = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gender);
        txtEmialaddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location);
        otherView = (View) findViewById(R.id.other_views);
        otherView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        facebooklogin = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.authButton);
        facebooklogin.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
                if (user != null) {
                    txtName.setText("Hello, " + user.getName());
                } else {
                    txtName.setText("You are not logged");
                }
            }
        });
        try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (android.content.pm.Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.d("KEy HASH :--", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT) + "PacakgeName:" + getPackageName());
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {

        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);

        }
       };

    private void onSessionStateChange(final Session session, SessionState state,
                                      Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged in..."+session.getAccessToken());

            Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {

                    if (user != null) {
                        otherView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        txtName.setText("Hello " + user.getName());
                        txtGender.setText("Your Gender: "
                                + user.getProperty("gender").toString());
                        txtEmialaddress.setText("Your Emial Address:" + user.getProperty("email"));
                        Log.i(TAG, "Logged in..." + session.getAccessToken());
                    }
                }
            }).executeAsync();
        } else if (state.equals(SessionState.CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Closed Login Failed");
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged out..." + session.getAccessToken());
            otherView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.i("Activity", "Start");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.i("Activity", "Stop");
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.i("Activity", "preexcute");
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                mSignInClicked = false;
            }
            mIntentInProgress = false;
            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.i("Activity", "Resume");
        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.i("Activity", "Pause");
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i("Activity", "Destroy");
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Log.i("Activity", "SaveInstanceState");
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_sign_in:
                signInWithGplus();
                break;
            case R.id.btn_sign_out:
                signOutFromGplus();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mSignInClicked = false;
        Toast.makeText(this, "User is connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        getProfileInformation();
        updateUI(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        updateUI(false);
    }

    private void signOutFromGplus() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            updateUI(false);
        }
        otherView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    private void getProfileInformation() {
        try {
            if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
                Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                        .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
                String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
                String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
                String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
                String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

                Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + personName + ", plusProfile: "
                        + personGooglePlusProfile + ", email: " + email
                        + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl);
                txtName.setText("NAME:" + personName);
                txtEmialaddress.setText("E-mail:" + email);
                personPhotoUrl = personPhotoUrl.substring(0,
                        personPhotoUrl.length() - 2)
                        + PROFILE_PIC_SIZE;

                otherView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                new LoadProfileImage(imgProfilePic).execute(personPhotoUrl);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Person information is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class LoadProfileImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public LoadProfileImage(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }

    private void updateUI(boolean isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
            btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    private void signInWithGplus() {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mSignInClicked = true;
            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }

    private void resolveSignInError() {
        if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                mIntentInProgress = true;
                mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                mIntentInProgress = false;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        if (!result.hasResolution()) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this,
                    0).show();
            return;
        }
        if (!mIntentInProgress) {
            mConnectionResult = result;
            if (mSignInClicked) {
                resolveSignInError();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that once the user logs in, it works successfully and give the user data, but when the user clicks on the logout button then it will not work properly, it will get the previous user login or user data.
Please someone, help me.

Comment: I used loginButton.registerCallback(...) instead of UserInfoChanged(). Could do the trick for you too

Comment: i was use the facebook-android-sdk- 3.23.1 so it can't use the registerCallback()

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your onCreate()

```
facebooklogin.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
```

it is working for me. I hope it is helpful to you.